# Извлечение из текста определённых символов. Вычисление среднего арифметического из полученных чисел.

Tags: html, javascript

Здравствуйте. У меня есть функция Javascript. Она вычисляет среднее арифметическое чисел. Но для того, чтобы ей это сделать, нужно убрать символы "н" и "-", которые могут содержаться в тексте. Но функция не работает... Можете подсказать, что я делаю не так?

```
setInterval(function mid() {
    var replace = "н-";
    var trA = document.getElementById("1.marks");
    var spA = trA.getElementsByTagName("span");
    var newTxt = spA.map(function() {
        if (replace.indexOf(spA) != -1) {
            return;
        }
        return spA;
    });
    t = 0;
    for (i=0;i<spA.length;i++) {
        t += parseInt(spA[i].innerText,10);
    }
    var midA = t/spA.length;
    var numA = Number((midA).toFixed(2));
    if (numA>0) {
        document.getElementById("1.b").innerText = numA.toFixed(2);
    }
}, 1);
```

Comment: Уже второй день сижу, но не могу найти проблему. Я пробовал менять некоторые переменные и значения, но от этого стало только хуже. В данном вопросе я показал исходный вариант.

Comment: @Никита___, очень мягко говоря, ничего в вашем коде не понятно. Во-вторых, id **не может** начинаться с цифры. В-третьих, почему бы вам не познакомиться с методом [map()][1]? В-четвертых, сделайте хоть полурабочий пример на [jsfiddle.net][2]

   [1]:https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
   [2]:http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Deonis, у меня ID начинается с цифры. И всё работает.

Comment: > у меня ID начинается с цифры. И всё работает.

Замечательно! Так держать ![alt text][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/iZ7fP9z.gif

Comment: @Deonis, если не изменяет память, в пятой спеке разрешили.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь регуляркой, чтоб убрать ненужные символы

```
var newText = oldText.replace(/[н\-]/g, '');
```

А затем перебирайте строку по символам с помощью цикла.

Answer (score 1):

[Пример в песочнице](http://jsfiddle.net/n7Lg9zdk/).

```
function mid() {
    var d = document,
        spans = d.querySelectorAll('#marks span'),
        output = d.querySelector('#b1'),
        sum = 0,
        avg = 0;
    [].forEach.call(spans, function (el) {
        sum += +el.textContent.replace(/[^\d]+/, '');
    });
    avg = sum / spans.length;
    if (avg > 0) output.textContent = 'Среднее арифметическое: ' + avg.toFixed(2);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо  того, чтобы задавать рандомные вопросы по js, лучше почитайте что-то толковое, например: Javascript. подробное руководство. 6-е издание (Флэнаган)